# Как можно узнать что объект вышел за пределы камеры?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно определить когда `Player` вышел за пределы видимой области

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У MonoBehaviour есть методы [OnBecameVisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html)  и [OnBecameInvisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html).
Срабатывают соответственно. Первый, когда объект начинается рендриться любой камерой, второй, когда перестаёт хотя бы одной.

Comment: Добавьте, что они работают и с камерой Редактора)